# InvalidArgumentError: unique expects a 1D vector

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I'm trying to create a customized loss function to use in a neural network algorithm.
My loss function:

```
import keras.backend as kb
import tensorflow as tf
def sign_penalty(y_true, y_pred):
    penalty=0.5
    loss=tf.where(tf.less(y_pred/y_true, 1),
                  penalty*(1-tf.dtypes.cast((((tf.unique_with_counts(y_pred >= y_true)[2])/(kb.sum(tf.unique_with_counts(y_pred >= y_true)[2])))[0]),tf.float32))+kb.sum((y_true - y_pred)**2/y_true),
                  kb.square(kb.sum((y_true - y_pred)**2/y_true)))
    return(loss)
```

The model used:

```
model_mlp = Sequential()
model_mlp.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=X_train.shape[1]))
model_mlp.add(Dense(1))
model_mlp.compile(loss=sign_penalty, optimizer=adam)
model_mlp.summary()
```

When I fit the model:

```
mlp_history = model_mlp.fit(X_train.values, Y_train, validation_data=(X_valid.values, Y_valid), epochs=epochs, verbose=2)
```

I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError:  unique expects a 1D vector.     [[node
> sign_penalty/UniqueWithCounts (defined at
> :3) ]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_773] Function call stack:
> train_function

I think that the error comes from the penalty, but I don't know why.

Comment: When you are fitting the data why are you passing in `X_train.values` instead of `X_train`?

Comment: Most probably because its a dataframe and `.values` gives its data as a numpy array

Comment: `y_pred >= y_true` is not 1D vector

Comment: @yudhiesh because X_train is a dataframe, so I have to change ir to an array to fit the model. However, Y_train is already an array, so I don't have to change it (with .values)

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Yes, X_train is a dataframe, so what should I do? Without .values I still get the same error

Comment: @Andrey So how can I get the percentage of the elements of y_pred that are smaller than the elements of y_true? So it is a 1D vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing 3D vector to `unique_with_counts`. Only 1D can be passed.

Try this simple approach to calculate percentage:

```
def sign_penalty(y_true, y_pred):
    penalty=0.5
    a = tf.cast((y_pred >= y_true)[2], tf.float32)
    s = kb.sum(a)
    percentage = a / s
    loss=tf.where(tf.less(y_pred/y_true, 1),
                  penalty*(1-percentage)+kb.sum((y_true - y_pred)**2/y_true),
                  kb.square(kb.sum((y_true - y_pred)**2/y_true)))
    return(loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I have printed y_true and y_pred:

```
tf.print(y_true)
tf.print(y_pred)
```

Came out that they were in one-hot representation.
Things started to work for me when I reversed them from one-hot representation:

```
y_true_c = tf.argmax(y_true, axis=1)
y_pred_c = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
```